# Custom url doesn't work in Django for views

Tags: python, django

I have the following setup in `proj.urls.py` :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1/prealert/', include('prealert.urls')),
]
```

Then in my app `prealert`, this is my setup for URLs (`prealert.urls.py`) , I have :

```
app_name = 'prealert'

urlpatterns = [   
    path('search_holding_certificate/',
         views.search_housing_certificate_view,
         name='search-hc')
]
```

This is my view :

```
@csrf_protect
def search_housing_certificate_view(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = HousingCertificateSearchForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            lot = ManagementByLot.objects.all()
            customer = form['customer'].value()
            product = form['product'].value()
            ware = form['ware'].value()
            season = form['season'].value()
            entity = form['entity'].value()
            url = f"{reverse('admin:prealert_managementbylot_changelist')}?customer={customer}&product={product}"

            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = HousingCertificateSearchForm()
        return render(
            request, 'admin/search_housing_certificate.html', {'form': form}
        )
```

When I access the view via this URL it **doesn't work**:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/prealert/search_holding_certificate/
```

unless I add on the default Django URL the word **admin** that's when it works:

```
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('api/v1/prealert/', include('prealert.urls')),
    ]
```

What causes this? Am using Django `4.0.3`